# How to automally run Tomcat 8 with window service way correcttly?

Tags: tomcat

recently,I have download Tomcat 8 installer.And I want to automally run tomcat server with window service way,（services.bat join to windows services）it can't be auto start.However,I only click start.bat,it can start well.

1. start mode is auto
2. I attemp to change start parma from "java" to
   "jvm",but it does't work.
3. [service.bat install pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmzM3.png)
4. [start up pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZc5T.png)

Comment: just click start.bat it can run well, that is to say it doesn't matter with "port","config".I doubt wether if have impact  with loading resources sequence .

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is? It looks like you have a correctly-configured Tomcat 8 service. Do you want it to auto-start but it won't auto-start, or do you want it to be a manual-start but it still auto-starts?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I dwnload from Tomcat offical web, it can run well.However,when I add in server.xml in tomcat , addtional config `<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener" rmiRegistryPortPlatform='10001' rmiServerPortPlatform='10002' />`.I want to start **jms service**.Because java's Serialization bug ** cve-2016-8735** that result in tomcat can't start with window service,though it can run well by click start.bat directly.

Answer (score 0):

I have find the rootcause. My tomcat have started JmX Service(1099 PORT) and java has bug about it that could be result in when click start tomcat service,occurs lightingly turn off.